# Get prediction from multiple rows - Decision Tree Regressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a dataset of weather data that I want to use to make a prediction.

The data set consists of data from several different locations. The features in the data set are as follows:

```
datetime
location
rain
snow
temp_min
temp_max
clouds
pressure
humidity
wind_speed
wind_deg
weather_description
```

The measurements have been made at the same time in all locations, which make it possible to distinguish between the individual measurements.

I want to use data from all locations as input with getting a prediction for a location.

Is it possible to use several lines as input or can input data only consist of one line?

Comment: it really depends on what you want to do. do you want to predict the scalar values at the next timestamp? do you want to do it based only on one location or take into account also the values at other locations? ...?

Answer (score 1):

The [`DecisionTreeRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html) from scikit-learn expects a dataframe where each output is generated based on a single row. You can nevertheless move all your measurements in into one row (during training and testing) as below:

```
rain_stn1, rain_stn2, rain_stn3, ..., snow_stn1, snow_stn2, snow_stn3, ...
rain_value@stn1, rain_value@stn2, rain_value@stn3, ...
```

Of course this means that there needs to be some logical relationship between the stations such as distance. You could also create aggregate values such as `rain_nearby` (average of stations at <5 km distance), `rain_far` (average of stations at >5 km distance) which is probably more helpful in your case.

To give more specific answers you need to provide more details on use case, what you are trying to achieve, and how the dataset looks like.

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm planning to fetch the data from openweathermap.org. One thing that I can't figure out is how to create a model that predict for example rain in the next hour. And base the prediction on multiple features.

Comment: This is a new question which should be posted in a new thread. Please outline clearly what you are trying to achieve. Given only the data that you have, I would argue that a decision tree might be a bit of an overkill and I would suggest that you use an ARIMA model or something alike taking only previous rain as input. Otherwise I would guess that a simple decision tree is unable to capture the necessary complexity. There is a reason why we have weather forecasting agencies with complex models after all ;-)